# Why am I unable to catch the Unexpected Alert Exception?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, behat, mink

I am using a try catch block to catch an exception and I am unable to catch it as it still says:

In Exception.php line 155:

```
  unexpected alert open: {Alert text : The form is not complete and has not been submitted yet. There is 1 problem with your submission.}
    (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.75)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 4.15.0-38-generic x86_64)
```

My feature file:

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Hook\Scope\AfterStepScope;
use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use WebDriver\Exception\UnexpectedAlertOpen;
/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements Context
{
    /**
     * Initializes context.
     *
     * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
     * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
     * context constructor through behat.yml.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @Given I fill in the email field with :email
     */
    public function iFillInTheEmailFieldWith($email)
    {

        dump($email);
        $this->visit('/471w2222');
        $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
        $page->find('xpath', '//*[@id="tfa_1111"]')->setValue($email);
    }


    /**
     * @When I submit the form
     */
    public function iSubmitTheForm()
    {

        try {
            $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
            $page->find('xpath', '//*[@id="submit_button"]')->click();
        }
        catch (UnexpectedAlertOpen $e){
            dd($e->getMessage());
            $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getWebDriverSession()->accept_alert();
        }

    }

}
```

The alert shows up :

```
$page->find('xpath', '//*[@id="submit_button"]')->click();
```

executes. But it is unable to catch it. Why?

Comment: Maybe you need a wait, wait up to 2-5 seconds for the alert + use page objects to clean the code.

Answer (score 1):

As per the error message...

```
(Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.75)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 4.15.0-38-generic x86_64)
```

...the main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.41*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.41*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v67-69**

- You are using *chrome=73.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.46*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v71-73**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.41* and the *Chrome Browser v73.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.46**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v73*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Good points however the issue is with exceptions. I upgraded but still the same error.